# Unable to install .NET Core on i386 Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: i386, ubuntu-16.04, coreclr

I was following the steps mentioned at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu  and other places my using i386 instead of amd64.
But encountering the following errors. Please help.

With i386

sudo apt-get update

[...]
Get:4 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet xenial InRelease [2,819 B]
Fetched 97.3 kB in 2s (42.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

In both cases i386 or amd64
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121'

Comment: Don't know why this post was voted down.

Comment: Having a similar problem.  I can't find it being addressed by anyone :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET Core documentation shows nothing on x86 architectures

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#preview

and some repos (I don't know if they are official) say nothing about it either.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

It's like they decided to evade an important part of the community.

Comment: I don't know how important we are, but it is problematic nevertheless :/ there seems to be some runtime support for 32bit atleast - can program in vs code without debugging